# Getting list of managers with salaries higher than non-manager employees

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a query to display a list of managers who have a salary greater than the maximum among other employees (not managers).

[data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXMmB.png)

Wrote an SQL query but it doesn't work and I can't understand why.

```
SELECT a.*, MAX(b.salary)
FROM employee a, 
     employee b
WHERE b.chief_id = a.id
  AND a.salary > max.salary
  AND a.chief_id IS NULL
```

I will be glad for good advice.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed! (If your lecturer says otherwise, switch to another class.)

Comment: @jarlh, could you show me how it's done, because I'm just a beginner

Comment: `FROM employee a JOIN employee b ON b.chief_id = a.id ...`

Comment: @jarlh And how can you understand the arrow in itself?

Comment: You could try using a subquery to compute the maximum value, and use it in your query, as a first attempt to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i understood correctly your goal, but if i got it right, no need to use a join, simply **use a nested query**.
Since i do not know what field contains the Manager/Non-Manager flag, i used a generic *ROLE* placeholder.
See if this suits you and you can adapt it.

```
SELECT          *
FROM            EMPLOYEE
WHERE           1=1
AND             ROLE = 'MANAGER' -- only select managers
AND             SALARY >    (SELECT MAX(SALARY)
                            FROM    EMPLOYEE
                            WHERE   1=1
                            AND     ROLE <> 'MANAGER') -- value of the max salary among non-managers
```

Edit: just saw the picture; if the Managers are those that have ID = CHIEF_ID, I suppose (they are so to speak "managers of themself" you might try with:

```
SELECT          *
FROM            EMPLOYEE
WHERE           1=1
AND             CHIEF_ID = ID -- only select managers
AND             SALARY >    (SELECT MAX(SALARY)
                            FROM    EMPLOYEE
                            WHERE   1=1
                            AND     CHIEF_ID <> ID) -- value of the max salary among non-managers
```

PS: the "WHERE 1=1" is just a condition i always use to make where conditions more flexible. You can remove it if you don't like it.